# Openfire database setup error

Tags: openfire

I am trying to install openfire on my VPS server.
The service is up and running. I am stuck in the database configuration step for the openfire server. I have created the database for openfire on my mysql server and imported the schema. However when I try to use those settings in the web based setup I get the following error:

```
A connection to the database could not be made. View the error message by opening the "/logs/error.log" log file, then go back to fix the problem.
```

The settings are as follows
JDBC driver class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Database url : jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/openfire_db

I have tried almost every possible setting but its not working.

Comment: I did not down vote you but you need to add more specifics to your questions here. Can you be more specific on the steps you took thus far? Also try providing log files and also links to the software you're trying to use would be helpful. If there were instructions you were following I'd include a link to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your logs configuration might not have been properly set.  Most 'nix systems don't have a /logs/* directory, (different and important from "logs/error.log" which would be a relative path to the service.)  Triple check that the logs are being written to a location that is sensible and writable.